# Calculating a distributional derivative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, tag-removed, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose that we have a sequence of functions $u_j$ that are in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$. Then the sequence of maps $N_j(s) := \|u_j(s)\|^2$ are also in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$. Hence they give rise to distributions and therefore has a distributional derivative. What is the explicit formula for $DN_j$? Is it related to the classical formula $2\langle u_j , Du_j\rangle$?

Comment: What is the norm $\|\cdot\|$ here?

Comment: Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I do not understand why do you need a sequence of functions when the question involves an individual function. Suppose that $u$ is real valued. Then the product of the distributions $u$ and $u'$ may not even be defined. (This is the case when $u$ is the  Heaviside function.) However, if  the distributional derivative of $u$ is Lebesgue integrable, then

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\; u^2\;) = 2u u'. $$